# How to I access a string in a nested Object?

Tags: javascript

How do I access string from a nested object? I am trying to return the number of pumpkin strings.

I guess I cannot use in for this. Should I access by index somehow? I am not exactly sure. All I need to know is how to access the string data.

```
let patch = {
  meadow: {
    byTheRock: 'apples',
    byThePuddle: 'pumpkin'
  },
  hill: {
    byTheBench: {
      leftOfBench: 'pumpkin',
      rightOfBench: 'pumpkin'
    },
    topOfHill: 'apples'
  }
};

function pumpkinPicker(patch) {
  console.log(patch)
  if('pumpkin' in patch){
    console.log('in')
  }
}

pumpkinPicker(patch);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a recursive function;

```
function totalPumkins(obj){

    let num = 0;

    for (let k in obj){
        if (typeof obj[k] === 'string' && obj[k] === 'pumpkin'){
            num++;
        }
        if (typeof obj[k] === 'object'){
            num += totalPumkins(obj[k])
        }   
    }

    return num;
}
```

```js
function totalPumkins(obj) {

  let num = 0;

  for (let k in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[k] === 'string' && obj[k] === 'pumpkin') {
      num++;
    }
    if (typeof obj[k] === 'object') {
      num += totalPumkins(obj[k])
    }
  }

  return num;
}


let patch = {
  meadow: {
    byTheRock: 'apples',
    byThePuddle: 'pumpkin'
  },
  hill: {
    byTheBench: {
      leftOfBench: 'pumpkin',
      rightOfBench: 'pumpkin'
    },
    topOfHill: 'apples'
  }
};

console.log(totalPumkins(patch));
```

Comment: Awesome! Why do you increment num within the first if statement?

Comment: The first if statement checks if current property is a string and then increases the count by 1. It happens when the code reaches a dead end (a goal). Otherwise, we try to go deeper into the object (recursion)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a recursive function and just check if the current element is an object:

- if yes, loop over all keys and call the recursive function again
- if no, check if the element matches the searched element

```js
let patch = {
  meadow: {
     byTheRock: 'apples',
     byThePuddle: 'pumpkin'
  },
  hill: {
     byTheBench: {
       leftOfBench: 'pumpkin',
       rightOfBench: 'pumpkin'
    },
    topOfHill: 'apples'
  }
};
    
const findNested = (obj, search) => {
  if(typeof obj === 'object') {
    let count = 0;
    for(let el in obj) {
      count += findNested(obj[el], search);
    }
    return count;
  } else {
    return obj == search ? 1 : 0;
  }
}
console.log(findNested(patch, 'pumpkin'))
```